# How can I make both external JavaScript files work in my html file?

Tags: javascript, html

The first JavaScript code works fine by itself, but when I add the other one it doesn't. I dont understand why.

When I remove the first JavaScript code the other code works fine too, but when I put them together the only js code that works is the first one. I need both of them to work but I can't figure it out.

**First js code**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
        position.coords.longitude);

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: 'Your Location.'
      });

      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

**Second js code**

```js
 var map, places, iw;
 var markers = [];
 var searchTimeout;
 var centerMarker;
 var autocomplete;
 var hostnameRegexp = new RegExp('^https?://.+?/');

 function initialize() {
   var myLatlng = new google.maps;
   var myOptions = {
     zoom: 17,
     center: myLatlng,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
   places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', tilesLoaded);

   document.getElementById('keyword').onkeyup = function(e) {
     if (!e) var e = window.event;
     if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
     document.getElementById('keyword').blur();
     search(document.getElementById('keyword').value);
   }

   var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');
   typeSelect.onchange = function() {
     search();
   };

   var rankBySelect = document.getElementById('rankBy');
   rankBySelect.onchange = function() {
     search();
   };

 }

 function tilesLoaded() {
   search();
   google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'tilesloaded');
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', searchIfRankByProminence);
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', search);
 }

 function searchIfRankByProminence() {
   if (document.getElementById('rankBy').value == 'prominence') {
     search();
   }
 }

 function search() {
   clearResults();
   clearMarkers();

   if (searchTimeout) {
     window.clearTimeout(searchTimeout);
   }
   searchTimeout = window.setTimeout(reallyDoSearch, 500);
 }

 function reallyDoSearch() {
   var type = document.getElementById('type').value;
   var keyword = document.getElementById('keyword').value;
   var rankBy = document.getElementById('rankBy').value;

   var search = {};

   if (keyword) {
     search.keyword = keyword;
   }

   if (type != 'establishment') {
     search.types = [type];
   }

   if (rankBy == 'distance' && (search.types || search.keyword)) {
     search.rankBy = google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE;
     search.location = map.getCenter();
     centerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: search.location,
       animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
       map: map
     });
   } else {
     search.bounds = map.getBounds();
   }

   places.search(search, function(results, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
       for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
         var icon = 'number_' + (i + 1) + '.png';
         markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
           position: results[i].geometry.location,
           animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
           icon: icon
         }));
         google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', getDetails(results[i], i));
         window.setTimeout(dropMarker(i), i * 100);
         addResult(results[i], i);
       }
     }
   });
 }

 function clearMarkers() {
   for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
     markers[i].setMap(null);
   }
   markers = [];
   if (centerMarker) {
     centerMarker.setMap(null);
   }
 }

 function dropMarker(i) {
   return function() {
     if (markers[i]) {
       markers[i].setMap(map);
     }
   }
 }

 function addResult(result, i) {
   var results = document.getElementById('results');
   var tr = document.createElement('tr');
   tr.style.backgroundColor = (i % 2 == 0 ? '#00FFFFFFF' : '#00FFFFFFF');
   tr.onclick = function() {
     google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
   };

   var iconTd = document.createElement('td');
   var nameTd = document.createElement('td');
   var icon = document.createElement('img');
   icon.src = 'number_' + (i + 1) + '.png';
   icon.setAttribute('class', 'placeIcon');
   icon.setAttribute('className', 'placeIcon');
   var name = document.createTextNode(result.name);
   iconTd.appendChild(icon);
   nameTd.appendChild(name);
   tr.appendChild(iconTd);
   tr.appendChild(nameTd);
   results.appendChild(tr);
 }

 function clearResults() {
   var results = document.getElementById('results');
   while (results.childNodes[0]) {
     results.removeChild(results.childNodes[0]);
   }
 }

 function getDetails(result, i) {
   return function() {
     places.getDetails({
       reference: result.reference
     }, showInfoWindow(i));
   }
 }

 function showInfoWindow(i) {
   return function(place, status) {
     if (iw) {
       iw.close();
       iw = null;
     }

     if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
       iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
         content: getIWContent(place)
       });
       iw.open(map, markers[i]);
     }
   }
 }

 function getIWContent(place) {
   var content = '';
   content += '<table>';
   content += '<tr class="iw_table_row">';
   content += '<td style="text-align: left"><img class="hotelIcon" src="' + place.icon + '"/></td>';
   content += '<td><b><a href="' + place.url + '">' + place.name + '</a></b></td></tr>';
   content += '<tr class="iw_table_row"><td class="iw_attribute_name">Address:</td><td>' + place.vicinity + '</td></tr>';
   if (place.formatted_phone_number) {
     content += '<tr class="iw_table_row"><td class="iw_attribute_name">Telephone:</td><td>' + place.formatted_phone_number + '</td></tr>';
   }
   if (place.rating) {
     var ratingHtml = '';
     for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       if (place.rating < (i + 0.5)) {
         ratingHtml += '&#10025;';
       } else {
         ratingHtml += '&#10029;';
       }
     }
     content += '<tr class="iw_table_row"><td class="iw_attribute_name">Rating:</td><td><span id="rating">' + ratingHtml + '</span></td></tr>';
   }
   if (place.website) {
     var fullUrl = place.website;
     var website = hostnameRegexp.exec(place.website);
     if (website == null) {
       website = 'http://' + place.website + '/';
       fullUrl = website;
     }
     content += '<tr class="iw_table_row"><td class="iw_attribute_name">Website:</td><td><a href="' + fullUrl + '">' + website + '</a></td></tr>';
   }
   content += '</table>';
   return content;
 }

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining two functions named `initialize()`. Either change name on one of them, to set them apart, or merge the code in to one function. As it is written, the second `initialize()` will overwrite/override the first (in order of load).

You could also define "namespaces" for your different js files. This will enable you to have the same function names, but you'll have to call them using their namespace (outside of the scope of the namespace anyway):

```
var yourNamespace = {
    initialize(): function() {
       //...
    }
}; 

var yourOtherNamespace = {
    initialize(): function() {
       //...
    }
};
```

And to call these:

```
yourNamespace.initialize();
yourOtherNamespace.initialize();
```